# Solr sort by function - Unexpected results

Tags: php, apache, solr, lucene, indexing

We're trying to query solr and sort results based on a complex function which involves several nested sum(...product(...div(...))) The function is very complex.
To debug things, we ran an SQL equivalent of the sort parameter calculation above and tried to match them on the same entities returned in the same order by solr above. We didn't see any matches. The more reliable SQL queries returned skewed results. The scores were all jumbled up and in no particular order. Which leads us to think that solr is unable to sort things here or we're doing something wrong.

Something fishy: fl=*,score yeilds same score values for all the documents returned. Is that factor still being sorted on?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Bump. Anyone? Solr version: 3.4.0.2011.09.09.09.06.17 so I'm guessing it's safe to assume the SOLR-1297 patch has been included.
Also, including and excluding the sort argument leads to different results.

Answer (score 0):

fl=*,score  is working as expected. It is giving different scores for different documents.
What version of solr are you using. I have tested it only on 3.6